# CakePHP 3 : Cookies tutorial

Tags: cakephp, cookies, e-commerce, shopping-cart, cakephp-3.2

Is there any good tutorial on CakePHP 3 cookie component.

I'm new to `CakePHP` and `Cookie` as well. I am writing an `e-commerce`application in `CakePHP 3.2` and want to used Cookie to build `shopping cart` which can store `item name`, `quantity`, and `price`.

Is there any good tutorial you can suggest to get hand on Cookie component of CakePHP.

I followed CakePHP documentation but I can only get about how to read and write to cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about cookies and how to use them in PHP [here](http://www.w3resource.com/php/cookies/cookies-in-php-with-examples.php), for specific information about using cookies in CakePHP [the CakePHP cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html) provides the best information.

Hope it helps